# Tkinter .grid() position in center of screen

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, I'm using the grid() to place my widgets and I want to position a widget, namely a label, in the middle of the screen. Does anyone know how to do this?

For example, the following code:
`widget.grid(row=0, column=1)`
I want the column to be 1 where there would be 3 columns (0, 1, 2) without having to place a widget in column 2.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking such a basic question. Show us a _minimal_, complete, working example that illustrates where you're getting stuck. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to achieve this, you need to know how many `rows` and `columns` your window will have.

For example if you simply have `3` rows and `3` columns (the minimum to be able to locate something in the center), then your screen will be split like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|              |             |             |
|      0,0     |     0,1     |     0,2     |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
--------------------------------------------
|              |             |             |
|      1,0     |     1,1     |     1,2     |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
--------------------------------------------
|              |             |             |
|      3,0     |     3,1     |     2,2     |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
--------------------------------------------
```

with the cells labelled as `row, column`.

So clearly if you have this setup you would want to set the `label` to `row 1` and `column 1`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's good, but I'd like it if I didn't have to place a widget in the column to centre something in column 1. Is it possible to place an invisible widget or something or another?

Comment: @JohnyNich what are you trying to achieve? By default, an element centres itself in a cell, just have one column then....

Comment: Is there a way to quickly establish how many rows & cols my tkinter window will have?

Comment: @ArduinoBen You'll have to keep track of how many elements you insert

Answer (score 0):

Since your parent frame has only 2 columns, you need to create a new frame at the bottom of the parent frame, with `columnspan=2`. Be sure to set the `row` as the lowest one.

For example, if your parent frame has 4 rows until now (0, 1, 2, 3), it would look like this:

```
new_frame = Frame(parent_frame, row=4, columnspan=2)
```

After that you just put whatever widget you want on that new frame, with just `.grid()` with no options.

Hope this helped.